# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on UEFI and erase Windows 8

Tags: uefi, hp

EQUIPMENT REPAIR FOR FRIEND:

[HP 19-2113w](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-19-2100-all-in-one-desktop-pc-series/6879095/model/7096373) ALL IN ONE PC With Windows 8 (sticker). I think they upgraded to Windows 10.

Just restored to factory default, (which restored to Windows 8). Seems to be working correctly.

I would like to install Ubuntu 18.04 but can’t get PC to see USB drive or an Ubuntu install DVD, think it has something to do with Secure Boot.  It says to disable Secure Boot (which I do in BIOS) and enable Legacy boot, (can’t because it is greyed out) when you try to restart PC, it says you can’t enable legacy unless you disable Secure boot which the menu says it is disabled.

I haven’t used Windows since XP, not sure what it will do. If I could just boot into my USB erase the HDD and install Ubuntu everything would be fine. Any ideas would be appreciated.

OPTIONS:
I have another 500gb HDD, if I put that in my Ubuntu computer, installed Ubuntu 18.04 then swapped HDD’s would the PC boot to Ubuntu without screwing with Secure Boot

Comment: Disable `Secure Boot`, `Fast Boot` and `OS Optimisation` in the BIOS, after this change the `boot order` so USB  and CD are before HDD/SSD, then `Save and Exit`. Then try the CD and USB again (try the USB ports on the back).

Comment: In Windows, please open a Command Prompt, run diskpart then do list disks. Please highlight and copy the text, then return here and click on edit. Paste the result of diskpart into your original question so we can see if your drive partition table is now MBR or GPT. ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html provides some background. And, if you install Ubuntu on a drive in a different PC, then mount that HDD in the HP, it won't blow up, and will probably work.